# How do I toggle and slide two forms on one page?

Tags: jquery, html

The idea here is to have two forms (or more) on one page, such as a Login Form and Reset Password Form show here in the example below. One form is hidden until a link is click, and and effect takes place. What I have here is a .toggle() effect which slides the loginform to the right, while the resetform is sliding in from the left. This occurs when the user clicks on the Forgot Your Password link.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <!--LOGIN FORM BEGIN-->
    <form id="loginform" action="login.php">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Log In Here!</legend>
            <label>Email Address:</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" maxlength="88" placeholder="myemail@example.com" />
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" maxlength="100" placeholder="password" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Log In" id="login" />
            <br />
            <br /> <span style="font-size:16px;"><a href="resetPassword.php" class="forgot">Forgot Your Password?</a></span> 
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <!-- LOGIN FORM END-->
    <!-- REST PASSWORD FORM BEGIN-->
    <form id="resetform" action="resetPassword.php">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Forgot Password?</legend>
            <label>Enter Your Email Address:</label>
            <input type="text" id="forgotpass" maxlength="88" placeholder="myemail@example.com" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Generate Password" id="GeneratePassword" />
            <br />
            <br /> <span style="font-size:16px;"><a href="login.php" class="backToLogin">Back to Login</a></span> 
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <!-- RESEST PASSWORD FORM END-->
</div>
```

Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#resetform').hide();
    $('a.forgot').click(function () {
        var page = $(this).attr('href').split(/\?/)[1];
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'resetPassword.php',
            data: page,
            success: function () {
                $('#loginform').toggle('slide', {
                    direction: 'left'
                });
                $('#resetform').toggle('slide', {
                    direction: 'right'
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

The problem is since the forms are stacked one on top of another, the loginform will slide left higher up on the page, the same time the resetform is sliding in from the right lower down on the page; then the resetform jumps up into the position replacing the loginform's position. Now I can play around with other effects such as; .hide() .show() .fadeIn() .fadeOut() .delay(), and time the effects with duration to achieve a cleaner look. But I was wondering if there is a simpler way of doing this in the HTML?

Comment: Do the forms have a fixed width by any chance?

Comment: Are you after this kind of thing: http://jsfiddle.net/8q34nvtg/1/? I'm alittle confused as your code is referencing the result of an ajax POST request, yet your question mentions clicking of links. This demo is based on link clicks.

Comment: Jon P- Each form has their own widths set: 500px 300px respectively. Don't be confused with the ajax POST. All I'm doing is switching my forms out when I click a link, so when the loginform leaves the page, the resetform takes over, and it gets posted to a different page.

Comment: Did you check out the fiddle in my previous comment? Is that the effect you are after?

Comment: I'll make that an answer!

Answer (score 1):

**DEMO: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/new6zr68/)**

Sounds like you need a callback function after the first one is run. Try this:

```
    success: function () {
        $('#loginform').toggle('slide', {
            direction: 'left',
            complete: function(){
                 $('#resetform').toggle('slide', {
                     direction: 'right'
                 });
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Well, this callback function does prevent the bottom resetform from beginning at the bottom and finishing at the top where the loginform used to be. However, when the loginform slides left and completes, the resetform slides right from the ending spot of the loginform and then jumps back to center.
It does work if I replace the .toggle('slide' with .fadeOut( and placing the callback function in that.

Comment: check out the fiddle i posted above. seems to be working fine.. if not, can you create a fiddle so that we can see the exact problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you are looking for with CSS transitions and a little jquery:

```js
$(".forgot").click(function(){
    $("#wrapper").addClass("logged");

    return false;
});

$(".backToLogin").click(function(){
    $("#wrapper").removeClass("logged");

    return false;
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    height:500px;
}

#wrapper form{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;    
    transition: all 2s ease;
}

#resetform
{
    transform: translateX(305px);
}

.logged #resetform
{
    transform: translateX(0px);
}

.logged #loginform
{
   transform: translateX(-305px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <!--LOGIN FORM BEGIN-->
    <form id="loginform" action="login.php">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Log In Here!</legend>
            <label>Email Address:</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" maxlength="88" placeholder="myemail@example.com" />
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" maxlength="100" placeholder="password" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Log In" id="login" />
            <br />
            <br /> <span style="font-size:16px;"><a href="resetPassword.php" class="forgot">Forgot Your Password?</a></span> 
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <!-- LOGIN FORM END-->
    <!-- REST PASSWORD FORM BEGIN-->
    <form id="resetform" action="resetPassword.php">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Forgot Password?</legend>
            <label>Enter Your Email Address:</label>
            <input type="text" id="forgotpass" maxlength="88" placeholder="myemail@example.com" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Generate Password" id="GeneratePassword" />
            <br />
            <br /> <span style="font-size:16px;"><a href="login.php" class="backToLogin">Back to Login</a></span> 
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <!-- RESEST PASSWORD FORM END-->
</div>
```